# How to represent two different types of data being returned by a class method in a UML diagram?

Tags: python, uml, class-diagram, return-type, representation

I have the following method:

```
    def getInvoiceById(self, id):

        for invoice in self.invoices:
            if invoice.id == id:
                return invoice

        return False
```

inside a class called `User`.
How do I represent the return type (after the Parenthese) in the UML class diagram? since it
can either be a Boolean or another class `invoice`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that this is a really bad implementation (you rather should return `None` than `False`) you would have the return type of what ever `ìnvoice` would be (probably `Invoice`). So assuming that it would just be

```
+getInvoiceById(id):Invoice
```

(I intentionally omit `self` since it is a mandatory parameter in Python.)

The exception can be noted as a constraint like `{ returns False if no id found }`.

Comment: could you explain why I should return none instead of a Boolean? my logic is that in conditional statements, the return type of the function would be used as the condition, thus, either returning false, or a class invoice instance (which would evaluate to true).

Comment: `None` is the absence of an object and thus represents exactly what you found. Any object in Python will be either an instance of a class or `None`.  False is a boolean value and should only be used in boolean logic.